# HQL Insert Query in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

I want to write an insert query in Grails. I have tried all possible combinations but cant get the syntax correct. Can anybody please help?

```
class Person {
    int age
    String name
}
```

i tried the following:

```
Person.executeUpdate("insert into Person  values (20,"ABC")")
```

p.s.:Please do not mention using save()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute a native query:

```
def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
sql.execute("insert into person values(?,?)", ["foo", "bar"])
```

note that `person` is the actual table name.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,
well to be honest my requirement is whenever a record is updated, rather than updating the record a new record should be inserted but with a different timestamp.

Is there anything out of the box in grails that I can use to implement this behaviour?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Will a record be updated via save()? e.g. person.save() creates a new person record with a new timestamp instead of updating the existing record?

Comment: How will this requirement fit into database constraints. Just think of a unique constraint on one row of your table. It would not work anymore. As far as I understand you, you want to hold information about changes made to a record. You should have a look at the Envers Plugin for that: http://code.google.com/p/grails-envers-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look possible. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct and note that it says "Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported; not the INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... form." So you can insert as a select from one or more other tables, but can't insert directly like you would with save().

Comment: Hi Burt thanks for your reply please check my comment on armandino's reply.